# Setting dpi flag in image files generated using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

We're using ffmpeg to batch out some TIFF images that are being resized and having white borders created to fit specific paper sizes.

The resulting images default to 72dpi, even when the source is 300dpi. Is there a way to set the dpi flag in the output file?

Many thanks :-)

Edit:

I have managed to answer my own question:

```
for %%a in ("*.tif") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf "scale=6974:4919:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=7016:4961:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=white,format=rgb24" -dpi 300 "%%~na A2 poster 594x420mm-Border.tif"
```

Comment: You might want to add imagemagick to the pipeline to set the dpi, I don't think there's anything in ffmpeg that deals with DPI at all.

Comment: Many thanks stib - I'd been looking at ImageMagick. It seems like that is the way to go!